# Monero GUI isn't synchronizing

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

I open and connect to the daemon.  The wallet says it's synched, but it's been two months since I've last opened the wallet.  There's no way it is synching and I've sent a deposit that isn't showing up.

Comment: I'm seeing this error:Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081

Answer (score 1):

Your daemon may have crash or been out of sync.
Considering the two month you mention, you should download the last 0.12.2 GUI [from the website](https://getmonero.org/downloads/) which solves a bunch of problems with the daemon.